# Laravel Lumen 5.7, debugbar throw Call to a member function listen on null

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, lumen, phpdebugbar

I'm trying to use the debugbar with lumen and jenssegers/laravel-mongodb , it wasn't showing the database queries so I enabled.

`\DB::connection('mongodb')->enableQueryLog();`

But now it shows this error.

### `Call to a member function listen() on null

in LaravelDebugbar.php line 354`

Another thing is that it only displays the debugbar on the home URL /, other than home URL it doesn't display the debugbar.

[image]

Without \DB::connection('mongodb')->enableQueryLog(); or \DB::enableQueryLog(); it renders, but doesn't show the database queries information, and it works with home page only.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Have you made sure your mongo db is actually functioning without debugbar... Because the error you are getting is because the application's service container's binding for 'db' is null...

Comment: @KurtFriars yes that is working fine, without the laravel debugbar, it only raise the error when I enable Without \DB::connection('mongodb')->enableQueryLog(); or \DB::enableQueryLog(); in the bootstrap/app.php

Comment: If you look [here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/blob/0a09f4cb8879e4e31394553b953410cd941fcda7/src/LaravelDebugbar.php#L287), you will see it is trying to resolve db out of the container, and that is what ```listen``` is being called on. So I dont know why debugbar wont resolve it, but your app will...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you put `\DB::connection('mongodb')->enableQueryLog();`?

According to this [issue on a master debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/issues/485) you need to call it on `AppServiceProvider.php`'s `boot()` function. Did you try that?

If this above not working, rather search help on [debugbar issues](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues), because I think that problem is with the plugin, not your code. And there is a many `Mongo` issues, definitely look there first.